# Ionic 3: BackgroundLocation updates are too rare

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I'm currently facing a problem that is not so nice. I already created an issue but no response. I need every location change to update the camera center position. But this doesn't happen. The refresh is not definable with time. It's just very rare for my needs. Android and iOS is the same. The log is called every minute or something like that.
Also I tried the console log outside the `ngZone` but it's the same.
This is what my configuration code looks like:

```
let config = {
  desiredAccuracy: 0,
  stationaryRadius: 1,
  distanceFilter: 0,
  debug: true,
  interval: 2000,
  pauseLocationUpdates: false,
  activityType: "AutomotiveNavigation"
};

this.backgroundGeolocation.configure(config).subscribe((location) => {
  // Run update inside of Angular's zone
  this.zone.run(() => {
    if(this.map) {
      this.map.getMyLocation().then( (userLocation: MyLocation) => {
        console.log("INSIDE ZONE Google Maps Location \n LAT: " + userLocation.latLng.lat + "\nLNG: " + userLocation.latLng.lng);
        this.userLocation = userLocation.latLng;
        this.speed = userLocation.speed;
        this.bearing = userLocation.bearing;
        this.altitude = location.altitude;

        this.cameraFollow();
        this.notify(this.nearestReports[0]);
      }).catch( error => {
        alert("Background - NO GPS FOUND: " + error);
      });
    }
  });
});

// Turn ON the background-geolocation system.
this.backgroundGeolocation.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using another Ionic Native plugin called [`Geolocation`](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/geolocation/).

There is a very handy `watchPosition()` function in there that looks like what you are looking for. Here's an example:

```js
let options = {
  enableHighAccuracy: true,
  timeout: Infinity, // don't return response until new ping is available from OS, to save battery
  maximumAge: 0
};

const subscription = this.geolocation.watchPosition(options)
  .filter((p) => p.coords !== undefined) //Filter Out Errors
  .subscribe(position => {
      console.log(position.coords.longitude + ' ' + position.coords.latitude);
});
```

Don't forget to stop the subscription when not needed in order to save battery:

```
subscription.unsubscribe();
```

Comment: But this plugin is not working for background location isn't it?

Comment: I'm not sure, honestly. I checked [how android handles the background location service](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestLocationUpdates(long,%20float,%20android.location.Criteria,%20android.app.PendingIntent)) though (that the plugin you use depends on) and it says `The elapsed time between location updates will never be less than minTime, although it can be more depending on the Location Provider implementation and the update interval requested by other applications`. So there really is not way to minimize it when in the background.

Comment: I hope this has answered your question.